# DataTable already belongs to another DataSet but solution doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying to use a XtraReport with a data source of datatable inside a dataset,
but when I open the report I get a web side error saying that the DataTable belongs to another DataSet

I have tried to use DataTable.Copy() but it does not show the data

I have ensured that data table has data

Answer (score 0):

it is a sample code you can use this : if copy is not worked you can use merge.

```
           dsLukuDetails.Tables.Add(dtLookUpDetails.Copy());
            dsLukuDetails.Tables[0].TableName = "dtLookUpDetails";
            this.DataSource = dsLukuDetails;
            this.DataMember = "dtLookUpDetails";
```

Comment: let me check this will help you